# Remove all files from folder which were in a zip

Tags: linux, bash, script

I accidentially unzipped an archive to the root of a disk instead of to a folder.

How can I remove all 188 files without doing it manually?

I now also have unzipped the files in the folder I want, so basically I need to remove all files in c:/dropbox which are also in c:/dropbox/myfolder, but recursively.

I'm on windows 10, but have also installed linux subsystem for windows, so it can be an unix-command too.

Answer (score 0):

I did

```
cd dropbox/myfolder
find . -type f -ok rm ../{} \;
find . -depth -type f -ok rmdir ../{} \;
```

I used -ok instead of -exex to be safe.
I did the find in two steps, so I wouldn't delete folders existing in the zip, but also existing already; folders with files remaining after the wrongly unzipped files removed shouldn't be deleted.